# Postgres syntax error on timestamp interval

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

Postgres here; I have a `Users` table that has the following fields:

```
create table Users ( 
    id bigserial primary key, 
    isAdmin boolean not null default false, 
    beginDate timestamp with time zone not null, 
    updated timestamp with time zone
);
```

I want to write a query that fetches any `Users` records that:

- Have a `beginDate` value within the last 24 hours (inclusively); **AND**
- Have an `updated` value that is *older* (exclusively) than 24 hours

My best attempt thus far is:

```
select *
from
Users
where
beginDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY and
updated < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

But this gives em the following error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "1"
  Position: 59

beginDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY and
                              ^
1 statement failed.

Execution time: 0.03s
```

Any ideas on what the fix is?

Comment: `INTERVAL '1' DAY`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax would be this:

```
beginDate >= NOW() - INTERVAL '1 DAY' and
updated < NOW() - INTERVAL '1 DAY'
```

You can find more information here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Still wrong... Use straight quotes, for the number only. See my comment.

Comment: @jarlh . . . This is correct.  Postgres accepts both.

Comment: Oops, I see. Sorry, @matias!